# Select and reposition and image in MS Word 2016

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a scientific writer. Sometimes I have repetitive tasks in large documents, and many documents per day. One task is to insert a single image in each page (different images for different pages) and position the image at the bottom left of the page (.45 inches right of page; 10.35 inches below top of page).

I tried to record a simple macro to use on each page after I inserted the image, but MS Word does not allow me to select an image while recording a macro.

I gather that VBA might help me, but I am unable to conceive of an approach; I have only rudimentary knowledge of VBA. I want to "take a preselected image and reposition it within the page."

SatxJoe

Answer (score 1):

I would normally ask you to show more own effort but I get that you are not a software engineer and working with images is fiddly. I took me quite some time to figure this out for my own application. Although it looks straightforward, it wasn't when I started.

Try below starter kit. You have to add your own error handling and whatever parameters and logic that you need. Also a keyboard shortcut would be handy.

It assumes that the image is not an inline image (see the positioning options in Word) but instead it 'floats' on the page. This makes it possible to reposition it. As the code for inline and non-inline is different, more code is needed. I've add the specific piece of code to get a selected inline image and make it non-inline - but commented out. Using error handling you can make the code work with both scenarios.

From your description it seems as if you need the image in the footer and have a different image on each page. That's not that straightforward - but ultimately doable. This code just repositions it on the page itself.

```
' TO DO: add error handling. Code assumes that the selection is the image
' If it is not then an exception is thrown

Dim selectedShape As Shape

' If the image is not an inline image
Set selectedShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes(Selection.ShapeRange.Name)

' If the image is an inline image then
' Set selectedShape = Selection.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape

With selectedShape
    ' Allow text to wrap around the image
    .WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapFront
    
    ' Fix the anchor (more stable repositioning)
    .LockAnchor = True
    
    ' Size the picture
    .LockAspectRatio = True
    .Height = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    
    ' Position the picture - use absolution position relative to page edges
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
    .Top = Application.InchesToPoints(10.35)
    .Left = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PageWidth - Application.InchesToPoints(0.45) - .Width
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.  I hope to read through your code and learn something. I also will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't entirely clear so here are my assumptions:

1. You are inserting an image in the body of the document, not the footer
2. The picture needs to be aligned to the left and bottom margins.

If these assumptions are correct you can achieve what you want with just a little setting up and without using any code.

There are three ways of adding a picture at that location:

1. Add a floating image
2. Add an inline image inside a borderless floating table aligned to the bottom left corner.
3. Add an inline image inside a paragraph styled with a frame aligned to the bottom left corner.

The last two options can be setup in advance using Picture Content Controls in place of the picture and saved as Quick Parts / Building Blocks. Then when you need to add the picture you simply insert the Quick Part and add the picture to it.

If you do need to add footers with specific images you can also make that easier by saving the footer(s) in the Footer gallery.

EDIT:
If you feel comfortable with a coded solution then I would suggest that rather than use code to solve an issue you use it to prevent one, i.e. you use code that both inserts and places the image. The first routine below will do that. As a bonus there is also a routine to move a selected image. Just copy and paste all the code below into a new module.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InsertPictureBottomLeft()
   Dim location As Range
   Set location = Selection.Range
   
   Dim filename As String
   filename = GetPictureFileName
   If filename = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
   
   Dim picture As Shape
   'add the picture
   Set picture = _
      ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(filename:=filename, _
      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Anchor:=location)
   LayoutPictureBottomLeft picture
End Sub

Public Sub MoveSelectedPictureBottomLeft()
   Dim picture As Shape

   On Error Resume Next
   Set picture = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
   'if selected picture is InlineShape we get an error
   If Err Then Set picture = Selection.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape
   'reset error handling
   On Error GoTo 0
   LayoutPictureBottomLeft picture
End Sub

Private Function GetPictureFileName() As String
   Dim dlgPicture      As Word.Dialog
   'display the picture dialog
   Set dlgPicture = Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
   With dlgPicture
      .Display
      GetPictureFileName = .Name
   End With
End Function

Private Sub LayoutPictureBottomLeft(picture As Shape)
   With picture
      .LayoutInCell = True
      .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
      .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTopBottom
      .Left = wdShapeLeft
      .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
      .Top = wdShapeBottom
      .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
      'for placement relative to page comment out previous 4 lines
      'and uncomment next 4 lines
      '.Left = InchesToPoints(0.45)
      '.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
      '.Top = InchesToPoints(10.35)
      '.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I look forward to trying things out. And, I look forward to studying what you have done and learning from it. I appreciate that you took the time to help me.